# The sum of the given sequence

Tags: summation

$49+50+\cdots+148$

I tried $49 + 148 = 197$. It's wrong apparently

I'm not sure what to do. Could I get some assistance?

Comment: See https://betterexplained.com/articles/techniques-for-adding-the-numbers-1-to-100/

Comment: What  do you suppose those "$\,\cdots\,$" dots stand for?

Comment: "It's wrong apparently" Do you really believe that $49+50+\dots+148 = 49 + 148$?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In general the sum of the first n numbers is given by

> $$s(n) =\frac{n(n+1)}{2}$$

thus

$s(148)-s(48)=49+50+\cdots+148$

Answer (score 1):

You should pair $49$ and $148$ up (great, you did that)

Now what about pairing $50$ with $147$?

You should count how many pairs are there and multiply with the number of pair.

Alternative perspective:

$$S= 49+50+\ldots + 148$$
$$S=148+147+\ldots+49$$

Add them up and solve for $S$.

Answer (score -1):

add 1+2+3...48 and subtract the same so net change is zero

now we have two series
1+2+3+4...148 and 1+2+3...48

$S_1 = 1+2+3+4...148 = 148*149/2$

$S_2 = 1+2+3+4...48 = 48*49/2$

S = 49 + 50...148

$S = S_1-S_2$

S1 = 11026

S2 = 1176

S = 9850